# Update search index after assets.onSaveAsset Event

Tags: plugins, events

I use an assets.onSaveAsset Event in my plugin to update a field with the IPTC-Data of the image.

```
  $asset->getContent()->keywords = $this->get_iptc_keywords($imgPath);
  craft()->elements->saveElement($asset);
```

It updates the field values of the asset, but it does not update the search index. When i resave the asset, the searchindex table is updatet and works. Is this a craft bug and is there a craft way to update the search index for a single element (not the full index). Otherwise do i need to update the index by writing plain sql update/insert statements? Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and listen to [`onBeforeSaveAsset`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetsService#onBeforeSaveAsset-detail) events instead of `onSaveAsset`. With [`onBeforeSaveAsset`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetsService#onBeforeSaveAsset-detail) you can modify the asset model before being saved, so you don't have to do that manually.